# What would cause a classic asp script to keep running after the ScriptTimeout value?

Tags: asp-classic

I have a classic asp script with the following line of code in it:

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 60*90;
```

which means that it will timeout after 90 minutes.

But it keeps going after the 90 minutes.  So there must be something else over-riding it.  There is no other setting of this variable in the script.

So my question is, what can override this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft documentation the timeout will not take effect while a server component is processing:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524831%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Maybe you are calling an external server component outside the realm of ASP and that is causing the script timeout to be ignored.